# How to combine and retrieve multiple columns from two tables in a Dataset

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, .net-4.5, dataview

I have a DataSet with two tables  connected by a  reference (Loop_id)

```
Table1
Column1  Column2        Loop_id
1        ItemCode_AAA     6
2        ItemCode_BBB     8

Table2
Column1       Loop_id
2014-Sep-09   6
2014-Nov-09   8
```

How do I retrieve all the columns, except loop_id from both tables to single table.
The resulting table should appear like

```
T1_Column1   T1_Column2       T2_Column1
1            ItemCode_AAA     2014-Sep-09
2            ItemCode_BBB     2014-Nov-09
```

I am using Net Framework 4.5

Comment: Did I misunderstand something in your question?  How does my solution work for you?

Comment: @paqogomez, the query does not understand the colum names, does not compile.

Comment: Check my edits.  That should work, though its untested.  Perhaps you could create a [fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net) if it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Linq to DataSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386943(v=vs.110).aspx):

To enumerate the table, call `AsEnumerable`.

```
DataTable table1 = ds.Tables["table1"];
DataTable table2 = ds.Tables["table2"];

var records = (from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
               join t2 in table2.AsEnumerable() 
                 on t1.Field<int>("Loop_id") equals t2.Field<int>("Loop_id") 
               select new {T1_Column1 = t1.Field<string>("Column1"),
                           T2_Column2 = t2.Field<string>("Column2"),
                           T2_Column1 = t2.Field<string>("Column1")});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)

Or you can use join

```
SELECT      T1.Column1 AS T1_Col ,   T1.Column2 AS T1_Col , T2.Column1 AS T2_Col

FROM            dbo.Table1 AS T1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Table2 AS T2 ON dbo.T1.Loop_id = dbo.T2.Loop_id
```